# Размер GropBox'а по контенту

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В общем, имею вот такой XAML:

```
 <GroupBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <GroupBox.Header>
                Настройка алгоритма
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <UniformGrid>
                <StackPanel >
                    <Label>Параметры алгоритма</Label>
                    <ListView MinHeight="100">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid>
                                    <Label></Label>
                                    <TextBox></TextBox>
                                </UniformGrid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel >
                    <Label>Настройка привязок результата работы алгоритма</Label>
                    <ListView MinHeight="100">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid>
                                    <Label></Label>
                                    <ComboBox></ComboBox>
                                </UniformGrid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </UniformGrid>
        </GroupBox>
```

И все это лежит в ячейке grid с `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>` и получается в итоге вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е внизу появляется какое-то незанятое место...

Как пофиксить?

Comment: поменяйте на Height="*"

Comment: Вы имеете в виду в родительском контейнере, где расположен GroupBox?

Comment: да, тогда заполнится все доступное пространство

Comment: @Gardes Мне что-то не помогло.

Comment: Дело в stackpanel, его элементы занимают место столько сколько им нужно, их нельзя растянуть. к тому же uniformgrid по умолчанию как я понял ставит 2 строки. Можете заменить uniformgrid и stackpanel на один grid